# Leading space does not conform to constraint in interface builder

Tags: ios, autolayout

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the leading space to superview is set at 0, but there is a gap between the superview margin and the UIView. Why is that and how can I make the leading space really 0?

The same goes for trailing space, by the way.

Comment: While you give leading constrain remove `Constrain to Margin` checkmark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select (double click) the constraint. Tap the selector for the `superview` item, and uncheck `Relative to margin`[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that you have not uncheck `Constrain to Margin` checkbox while adding leading or trailing constraint.

Remove that constraint add it agin without checkbox:

[image]

**OR**

Select leading constraint and in `size inspector` remove check of  `Relative to margin` in `second item`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pls, uncheck **Constraint to margin** Checkbox in Add New Constraints Dialog before give the Constraints like this :

[image]